# Find magnitude of 8D vector using python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, vector, magnitude

I am trying to get output of primary capsule layer in capsule network. According to that I get 1152 number of 8D capsules. 
Here is one example

```
[ 0.19123563 -0.11994515 -0.7150253  -0.35917872 -0.02346791 -0.32390958
0.40772104 -0.01656894]
```

I am finding its magnitude using `np.linalg.norm()`. Accordingly magnitude is `0.98143137`.I don't understand how this is calculated.

Comment: It is of cause not possible to visualize 8D data, however, you can try tools like https://github.com/lmcinnes/umap to see an approximated  8D vector in 2D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The magnitude is the square root of the sum of the squares of all the entries of the vector. The following code would give you the same value: `np.sqrt(np.sum(vector**2))`. As far as graphing this, I'm unsure of what you are trying to visualize.